# Unable to get access token for splitwise python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

Using the third-party python SDK listed on https://dev.splitwise.com/#section/Introduction

```
from splitwise import Splitwise
from splitwise.expense import Expense
from splitwise.user import User

consumer_key = <xxx> 
consumer_secret = <xxx>
#masked for security, I have the key and secret and tested them as well

s = Splitwise(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/'

url, state = s.getOAuth2AuthorizeURL(redirect_uri)

access_token = s.getOAuth2AccessToken(code, redirect_uri)
```

Unable to figure out what needs to be passed as code.
Official docs are unclear as well: https://splitwise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authenticate.html#authenticate

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you posted:

```
Step 1. Register your app on splitwise to get a *consumer key* and *consumer secret*.
```

Probably, after registering, go to settings, than get that piece of data.
It will be your `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` variables.

Comment: I already have consumer_key and consumer_secret, can't post those so masked.

Comment: what errors are you having then ?